# Create mongo user with right to read local database

Tags: mongodb

I would like to create a mongo user who can read local database. I try to use command on local database:

```
db.createUser(
  {     user: "readonlyuser", pwd: "loh8Ephi",
    roles: [ { role: "read", db: "local" } ]
})
```

But - it doesn't work. I receive:

```
connecting to: local
2015-12-21T14:08:07.904+0100 Error: couldn't add user: Cannot create users in the local database at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1054
```

I've tried to create that user against admin database:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.createUser(
...   {     user: "readonlyuser", pwd: "loh8Ephi", roles: [ { role: "read", db: "local" } ] })

Successfully added user: {
"user" : "readonlyuser",
"roles" : [
    {
        "role" : "read",
        "db" : "local"
    }
]
```

And now i try to connect:

```
undefine@machine:~$ mongo -u readonlyuser -p loh8Ephi local
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: local
2015-12-21T15:35:19.190+0100 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1292
exception: login failed
```

How to create readonly user who have access only to local database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#local-database), you cannot create users on the local database. Instead you can run your `createUser` query against the `admin` database:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
 {     user: "readonlyuser", pwd: "loh8Ephi",
   roles: [ { role: "read", db: "local" } ]
})
```

Please note that you will have to authenticate against the `admin` database when connecting.

Comment: ok, i've created that user in admin database:
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.createUser(
...   {     user: "readonlyuser", pwd: "loh8Ephi", roles: [ { role: "read", db: "local" } ] })

Successfully added user: {
 "user" : "readonlyuser",
 "roles" : [
  {
   "role" : "read",
   "db" : "local"
  }
 ]
And now i try to connect:
undefine@machine:~$ mongo -u readonlyuser -p loh8Ephi local
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: local
2015-12-21T15:35:19.190+0100 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1292
exception: login failed

Comment: You need to authenticate against the `admin` database.

Comment: ok, it works, but... then that user have right to connect to admin database:

    undefine@undefine-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ mongo -u readonlyuser -p loh8Ephi --authenticationDatabase admin admin
    MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
    connecting to: admin

And i want to create user which have only right to local, not admin database :-)

Comment: The user only has the right to authenticate itself against the admin database, it has no other permissions.

Comment: i've connected as this user to admin database - and i can create colections. so - i've other permissions :-)

Comment: Are you runnng the mongod instance with --auth ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98582/discussion-between-undefine-and-jaco).

Comment: Ok, my fault - i had two different configs - one(mongodb.conf) from previosly installed mongodb-server, where i've set auth=true, and second(mongod.conf) from mongodb-org-server, where i've not set... Now it works fine, thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like below

```
use admin
db.getSiblingDB("local").runCommand( { "createUser" : "mongoread", "pwd": "read0nly", "customData" : { "description": "mongo readonly user" }, "roles" : [ {"role" : "read","db" : "local"}] },{ w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 } );
```